# Update mysql from v5.1 to v5.6, can not connect mysql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, utf-8, utf8mb4

I would like to update mysql from v5.1 to v5.6, so that we can use utfmb4 instead of utf8.
After I updated my mysql, I changed the hibernate conf file connection url  to
jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/app?characterEncoding=utf8mb4, i.e. utf8 to utf8mb4 and
then I failed to connect  db. If I changed it back to utf8, it worked.

The error info:
 com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source

pls help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help: 
http://info.michael-simons.eu/2013/01/21/java-mysql-and-multi-byte-utf-8-support/

Best regards,